# Q objects are not subscriptable in django - lambda expression

Tags: django, lambda, django-views, django-q

Am facing an error : "Q objects are not subscriptable" in below line of codes :

```
        input = [{"sid":1,"st":7},{"sid":2,"st":5},{"sid":3,"st":9},{"sid":4,"st":7},{"sid":5,"st":9},{"sid":6,"st":7}]
        queries = [Q(sid=i['sid'], st=i['st']) for i in input]
        sid_query = reduce(lambda x,y: (x['sid'] == y['sid']) & (x['st'] >= y['st']), queries)  # IN THIS LINE
        queryset=cube.objects.values_list('pid').filter(sid_query)
        res = list(queryset.values())
```

Am trying to fetch pid's from the rows which has combination of (sid and st) values. sid should be equal to sid from my input and for st should be greater than or equal to st value for respective sid.

This is how mysql table looks like:

[image]

Here is my Model:

```
class cube(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    av = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sid = models.IntegerField()
    st = models.IntegerField()
```

If I have input as [{"sid":1,"st":5},{"sid":2,"st":5}]
my query should return pid for below condition - note that there are 10 rows for each pid for different combination of sid and st values.

(sid=1,st>=5) and (sid=2,st>=7)

This should result two pids - 3214 and 3215 as per my table.

What am I missing ?

I understand that 'object is not Subscriptable' is thrown for containers which implements __getitem() function doesn't work, how can I fix this on Q objects in my query ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in that reduce call. What are you hoping to compare?

Comment: I used it to combine the queries to a single value.. I just removed it and tried executing the view - it fails with error msg "function' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: Well, you need to combine them somehow, but usually you would just do `reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, queries)`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I already tried this.. It will not return any results for AND condition.. For that reason, I specifically used "(x['sid'] == y['sid']) & (x['srt'] >= y['srt'])" within lambda expression inside reduce()